# Anyone aware of a browser where HTTPS can be disabled entirely for negative testing?

Tags: test-design, requirements-validation

I'm looking for a way to have a negative test result on a site requiring HTTPS that has a http->https redirect. I already have steps showing the redirect, and I can use the --ssl-version-max=ssl3 flag in Chrome to make the request fail, but I'd rather not have to explain why SSLv3 is *essentially* like not having SSL at all.

Comment: Does this help? http://disablessl3.com/

Comment: Not really. Appreciated, but that's more geared towards preventing POODLE attacks. I can already show that my webserver won't do anything lower than TLS1.0. I want to have objective evidence that HTTP won't work at all, but since the server redirects HTTP GET requests to HTTPS, I need a browser that won't do HTTPS at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [oldweb.today](http://oldweb.today)
for example [here is](http://oldweb.today/ie4/20011105151405/https://www.google.com/) IE4 rejecting https://google.com since it is HTTPS.